# Should questions on how to circumvent safety mechanisms be discouraged?

Tags: discussion

- [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't allow questions on personal health due to liability
- [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't allow questions on personal legal quandaries for similar reasons
- Mechanics.SE and DIY.SE Don't have active policies, but they downvote (into oblivion) questions where the user shows a lack of understanding and might hurt themselves based on what they're asking how to do.

Someone recently proposed a question [asking for help on how to circumvent safety mechanisms in place by his company](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/15823/reading-glasses-with-zero-correction). I could see similar questions on how to prevent the safety lock on a lighter, workaround lockout procedures, etc. It seems like life hacks might be the kind of place individuals would come to find this kind of information. For Liability reasons (among others) I'm fairly certain this is the type of question SE should avoid answering, and discourage the asking of.

Comment: Related: https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2689/6973

Answer (score 6):

I think this ought to fall under [the normal guidance for downvoting](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), specifically the following:

> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps ***dangerously*** incorrect.

Emphasis mine.

[Some questions](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/8021/15) have received numerous downvotes because of their disregard for safety. [Some answers](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/15290/15) as well, though they have generally been deleted under spam or not constructive.

On the flip side, I see more [questions](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/4007/15) and [answers](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/9866/15) and [comments](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/508/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-defrost-a-frozen-chicken-breast/510#comment2004_510) specifically seek to *avoid* dangerous situations.

And those are rightfully upvoted.

If you do see a question that makes you concerned for the personal safety of a user, go ahead and flag it and let us know why.

Comment: The quote is about answers. Dangerously stupid Qs should have their danger addressed in the As. There should be very few bad Qs based on this criteria. Danger in answers is a whole different story.